# Where can I find a comprehensive list of compatible USB devices?

Tags: hardware, usb, compatibility

I need a Ubuntu compatible Video grabber for USB, composite/S-Video + analog audio. Most has compatibility with Windows/MacOS listed on the manufacturer/retailers homepage but I need to check if Ubuntu is supported before I buy.

I know that Ubuntu supports many devices on the chip set level so what the manufacturer states regarding Ubuntu compatibility is not necessarily final.

I checked this [compatibility database](http://www.linuxcompatible.org/compatdb/index.html) mentioned in an answer to another question regarding Audio Card compatibility but that list did not seem comprehensive. E.g it did not list the DLink DUB-E100 USB2.0 Ethernet adapter that I successfully have used on my Ubuntu 11.04 Laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looking at the following link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB

Especially, check the [compatible hardware](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport) section.

You can also check the [Hardware Component Catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/USB) for things that are certified to work.